# Fusion Table Map Not Displaying on Mobile Version of Website

Tags: javascript, mobile, maps, google-fusion-tables, css-tables

This is my first time using Javascript and I have pieced together code to display my Google Fusion Table on a website. 
The website has a mobile version but the map does not appear when on mobile (It functions perfectly on the web version). 
I used a service called **Weebly** to create the website and it generates a mobile version for you, thought I don't know if that has anything to do with the problem.

Can anyone help me out altering my code to allow the map to work on mobile?

I am pretty lost here. I know there are IsMobile lines, but I don't know how to alter them properly.

**Here is the code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport"></meta>
<title>ProjectsR5(Revised) - Google Fusion Tables</title>
<style type="text/css">
html, body, #googft-mapCanvas {
}
}
#panel {
        position: absolute;
        top: 5px;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -180px;
        z-index: 5;
        background-color: #fff;
        padding: 5px;
        border: 1px solid #999;
      }

</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&amp;v=3"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function codeAddress() {
  var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
  geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
      map.setZoom(11);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          position: results[0].geometry.location
      });
    } else {
      alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
    }
  });
}
var geocoder;
var map;
  function initialize() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    google.maps.visualRefresh = true;
    var isMobile = (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('android') > -1) ||
      (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPod|iPhone|iPad|BlackBerry|Windows Phone|iemobile)/));
    if (isMobile) {
      var viewport = document.querySelector("meta[name=viewport]");
      viewport.setAttribute('content', 'initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes');
    }
    var mapDiv = document.getElementById('googft-mapCanvas');
    mapDiv.style.width = isMobile ? '40%' : '950px';
    mapDiv.style.height = isMobile ? '40%' : '600px';
    map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.57633626219805, -119.83481312667385),
      zoom: 7,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM].push(document.getElementById('googft-legend-open'));
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM].push(document.getElementById('googft-legend'));

    layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
      map: map,
      heatmap: { enabled: false },
      query: {
        select: "col5",
        from: "1KbXpf6FSzsFQt3rIpVP5ruIR_Pij87dgy2HwjyLi",
        where: ""
      },
      options: {
        styleId: 2,
        templateId: 2
      }
    });

    if (isMobile) {
      var legend = document.getElementById('googft-legend');
      var legendOpenButton = document.getElementById('googft-legend-open');
      var legendCloseButton = document.getElementById('googft-legend-close');
      legend.style.display = 'none';
      legendOpenButton.style.display = 'block';
      legendCloseButton.style.display = 'block';
      legendOpenButton.onclick = function() {
        legend.style.display = 'block';
        legendOpenButton.style.display = 'none';
      }
      legendCloseButton.onclick = function() {
        legend.style.display = 'none';
        legendOpenButton.style.display = 'block';
      }
    }
  }

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script>
</head>

 <body>
    <div id="panel">
      <input id="address" type="textbox" value="Your Project Location">
      <input type="button" value="Search" onclick="codeAddress()">
    </div>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>

<body>
  <div id="googft-mapCanvas"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

the `<body/>` needs to have a height set via CSS, otherwise the browser isn't able to calculate the 40% for the height of the map in this line:

```
mapDiv.style.height = isMobile ? '40%' : '600px';
```